# Prolog: How can I set "gtrace" correctly in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prolog

I have [SWI-Prolog 8.2.4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable/bin/swipl-8.2.4-1.x64.exe.envelope) installed, and I was trying to get it to work in Visual Studio Code with the extension "[VSC-Prolog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arthurwang.vsc-prolog)" made by Arthurwang.

If I try to run a program, everything works correctly, however I realized that I cannot use the `gtrace` tool, because when I try to do it, a strange message appears on the console asking me if I was not wrong and I wanted to write "trace" (which is something different than what I'm looking for).

What I tried later is to write `gtrace` in the console but outside of Visual Studio Code to see if there I could make use of that tool. However, the same problem appears:

[image]

However, if I open swi-prolog's default text editor (swipl-win.exe), `gtrace` works fine there.

[image]

Why could this be happening, and how could I fix it?

Hope I can use prolog correctly in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This is a comment instead of an answer because while it may be the actual answer it is not the answer you desire. As one who uses VSCode with SWI-Prolog and uses gtrace when needed, even as I write, I gave up on trying to achieve what you seek. I just use VSCode for editing and the SWI-Prolog top level for running queries and even queries with gtrace/0. If you want to find others that use VSCode with SWI-Prolog you might find someone at the [SWI-Prolog Discourse forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/). If you do post this question there, note here and there that you double posted.

Comment: [gtrace/0](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=guitracer) for those interested. Ran out of space in the first comment.

Comment: I checked the plugin page and it does appear the plugin supports [gtrace style debugging](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arthurwang.vsc-prolog#debugger) but I have never been able to get it to work. It also notes that using with the debugger is experimental.

Comment: Apparently the problem is not with the VSC plugin, but with the prolog console itself, which is not detecting several modules from the main library. I tried reinstalling and adding to Path manually but it didn't work.

Comment: `Apparently the problem is not with the VSC plugin, but with the prolog console itself`, Perhaps you should post this question at the [SWI-Prolog Discourse Forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) then [Jan W.](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commits/master) the creator and maintainer of SWI-Prolog can add some knowledge and/or fix the code. He does patches at times within hours and can pick it from GitHub or wait the next day and pick it up in the daily build.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing SWI-Prolog gtrace be driven from within VSCode. :) If you join the forum, then let me know, I am [EricGT](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/u/EricGT).